# Eliminar Registros duplicados en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente Query con la cual obtengo la cantidad de veces que se repite cada *id_tercero* en mi tabla *rol_por_tercero*.

`use DatabaseName
select id_tercero,COUNT(*)CantidadRepetidos from rol_por_tercero group by id_tercero having COUNT(*)>1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero eliminar un registro de los que se repiten para cada id y dejar el otro ya que por lo generan todos los id se repiten dos veces

la tabla en la cual existen estos registros, se llama *rol_por_tercero* y el campo se llama *id_rol_tercero*. Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Es valido, gracias

Comment: Si no tienes una llave primaria, entonces no se puede eliminar solamente un registro porqué no hay forma de diferenciarlos, aún así lo que puedes hacer es insertar los registros únicos en un tabla temporal, luego eliminar todos los de la tabla, e insertar los de la temporal

Comment: Utiliza INSERT INTO #temporal (id_tercero, ...otros), SELECT DISTINCT id_tercero, ...otros FROM rol_por_tercero

Comment: Usar cursores es pecado

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, dicha pregunta solo aplica para `sql`, pero hay alternativas mejores para la eliminación de registros en `sql-server`. Podrías revisar [DEMO](http://rextester.com/NXOMU95664)

Answer (score 1):

Crea una tabla temporal con la misma estructura que tu tabla principal.
Con un cursor obtén todos los ids, y que no aparezcan repetidos, ello lo obtienes escribiendo:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_tercero ...
```

Haciendo uso de SELECT TOP 1 y filtrado por el ID, rescatas un registro y lo almacenas en la tabla temporal. Culminado el bucle en la tabla temporal tendrás un registro de cada uno de los casos sin necesidad de que se repita.